# How to push to a git repository with LibGit2Sharp using SSH Keys?

Tags: c#, git, ssh, ssh-keys, libgit2sharp

I have a C# application, which can clone/push the user git repository with basic authentication (user/pass) and with OAuth token, but how can I provide my ssh key to do the same?

I searched the LibGit2Sharp.Credentials library, but I can't find a way how to set the ssh keys.

Is this feature implemented in LibGit2Sharp?

I know there is a [LibShh2 library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/libssh2/) for C projects, but what about C#?

Is it possible to use SSH keys?